# How to know if the motherboard replacement of my macbook pro is new?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have recently noticed an application that I have not installed on my macbook pro, which has a creation date prior to the installation of the new motherboard. How could I know the date of manufacture of the replacement plate?

Comment: Manufacture dates are often printed on the boards. Or revision numbers can be checked.

Comment: What's the connection between an app with a creation date older than the mobo replacement & the age of the mobo itself? This feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)